# Bootstrap main element goes behind sidebar

Tags: html, css, python-3.x, django, bootstrap-5

I am using the Dashboard example from Bootstrap 5: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/dashboard/. It runs fine when I open the html file outside of my app. But then I add it to my Django Web App and the  element goes behind the side bar as shown below, which leaves a gap on the right side of the page:
[image: This is what the page currently looks like, notice the gap down the right side]

The page should look like this, where the graph doesn't go behind the sidebar

[image: This is what the page should look like]

Here is the relevant code I'm using:

**Dashboard.html:**

```
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Dashboard Template for Bootstrap</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'appbase.css' %}">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark sticky-top bg-dark flex-md-nowrap p-0">
    <a class="navbar-brand col-sm-3 col-md-2 mr-0" href="#">Company name</a>
    <input class="form-control form-control-dark w-100" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
    <ul class="navbar-nav px-3">
        <li class="nav-item text-nowrap">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign out</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <nav class="col-md-2 d-none d-md-block bg-light sidebar">
            <div class="sidebar-sticky">
                <ul class="nav flex-column">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" href="#">
                            <span data-feather="home"></span>
                            Dashboard <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                            <span data-feather="file"></span>
                            Orders
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                            <span data-feather="shopping-cart"></span>
                            Products
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                            <span data-feather="users"></span>
                            Customers
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                            <span data-feather="bar-chart-2"></span>
                            Reports
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                            <span data-feather="layers"></span>
                            Integrations
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <h6 class="sidebar-heading d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center px-3 mt-4 mb-1 text-muted">
                    <span>Saved reports</span>
                    <a class="d-flex align-items-center text-muted" href="#">
                        <span data-feather="plus-circle"></span>
                    </a>
                </h6>
                <ul class="nav flex-column mb-2">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                            <span data-feather="file-text"></span>
                            Current month
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                            <span data-feather="file-text"></span>
                            Last quarter
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                            <span data-feather="file-text"></span>
                            Social engagement
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                            <span data-feather="file-text"></span>
                            Year-end sale
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <main role="main" class="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 pt-3 px-4">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom">
                <h1 class="h2">Dashboard</h1>
                <div class="btn-toolbar mb-2 mb-md-0">
                    <div class="btn-group mr-2">
                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Share</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Export</button>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle">
                        <span data-feather="calendar"></span>
                        This week
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <canvas class="my-4" id="myChart" width="900" height="380"></canvas>
        </main>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../../../assets/js/vendor/jquery-slim.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<script src="../../../../assets/js/vendor/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Icons -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/feather-icons/dist/feather.min.js"></script>
<script>
    feather.replace()
</script>

<!-- Graphs -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
            datasets: [{
                data: [15339, 21345, 18483, 24003, 23489, 24092, 12034],
                lineTension: 0,
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                borderColor: '#007bff',
                borderWidth: 4,
                pointBackgroundColor: '#007bff'
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: false
                    }
                }]
            },
            legend: {
                display: false,
            }
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

appbase.css

```
body {
  font-size: .875rem;
}

.feather {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
}

/*
 * Sidebar
 */

.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100; /* Behind the navbar */
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: inset -1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

.sidebar-sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 48px; /* Height of navbar */
  height: calc(100vh - 48px);
  padding-top: .5rem;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto; /* Scrollable contents if viewport is shorter than content. */
}

.sidebar .nav-link {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #333;
}

.sidebar .nav-link .feather {
  margin-right: 4px;
  color: #999;
}

.sidebar .nav-link.active {
  color: #007bff;
}

.sidebar .nav-link:hover .feather,
.sidebar .nav-link.active .feather {
  color: inherit;
}

.sidebar-heading {
  font-size: .75rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

/*
 * Navbar
 */

.navbar-brand {
  padding-top: .75rem;
  padding-bottom: .75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  box-shadow: inset -1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
}

.navbar .form-control {
  padding: .75rem 1rem;
  border-width: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.form-control-dark {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
}

.form-control-dark:focus {
  border-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, .25);
}

/*
 * Utilities
 */

.border-top { border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5; }
.border-bottom { border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5; }
```

Comment: You are using a template from bootstrap 4.0 but running 5.0 in your app. Some of the class names changed between the two versions, could be your issue. try the 5.0 dashboard https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/dashboard/

Comment: @Wazy thanks, it works now, I don't know how I ended up using 4.0 instead of 5.0. Thanks